# Mysql update date relative to specific column update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a *users_settings* table on my db in which I store some data about the user. For some of that data I need to **keep track of last modification**, for example:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| Field        | Type        |
+--------------+-------------+
| feel         | varchar(10) |
| feel_last    | timestamp   |
| other        | varchar(10) |
| other_last   | timestamp   |
+--------------+-------------+
```

When I update the row with a new *feel* value I want to automatically write the current timestamp, is it possible to achieve this directly from mysql or I need to set the timestamp directly in the update query from my backend?

---

### Update 1

As suggested I need to use a trigger, I written this trigger but there is some syntax error, can you help me to identify the error?

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_feel_last BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.feel <> OLD.feel THEN
    SET NEW.feel_last := now();
  END IF;
END;
```

### UPDATE 2

> - For who use AWS RDS: the parameter "log_bin_trust_function_creators" isn't enabled by default, to create triggers it's necessary, here a small guide to set it: https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

Now, thanks to James answer I created the trigger, it works well

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_feel_last_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

if(old.feel<>new.feel)
then
 set new.feel_last=current_timestamp;
elseif( old.feel = NULL )
then 
 set new.feel_last=current_timestamp;
end if;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Use a trigger to update the timestamp.

Comment: For every field you have a timestamp to record the last change to that field? I might be inclined to dump those timestamps and archive the whole table on an update to any column and use code to check what changed.

Comment: Not need for every field, just for one or two...

Comment: I would still archive else how would you know what it looked like before and whodunit.

Comment: @jarlh tnx I'm looking to how setup the right trigger, you my have same useful example?

Comment: which MySQL version you are using? btw in which column you are tracking `feel_last`?

Comment: I use 8.0.15 and I want to track the last update of "feel" by writing a timestamp on "feel_last"

Comment: `ALTER TABLE users_settings 
CHANGE COLUMN feel_last feel_last  TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;` you can try this?

Comment: Yes but this update the timestamp also if I update the row but feel value remain the same, I want to update feel_last only when the value of feel change

Comment: Okay i get it now. So the row used to update but you need to keep track only when `feel` changes. then you need a trigger.

Comment: If error share it.

Comment: @red Don't use `=` to compare `NULL` values use `IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below trigger on `BEFORE UPDATE`

```
BEGIN

if(old.feel<>new.feel)
then

 set new.feel_last=current_timestamp;

end if;

END
```

Comment: Tnx, It's not working but I think thats the problem isn't your code but the permission in aws rds, now I try with fixed permissione and I'll share the results with you

Comment: Yeah.. since in my local it worked..try let us know

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is not necessary in MySQL.  This functionality is happily built in.  You can define the table as:

```
create table users (
    . . .,
    update_datetime datetime default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);
```

You can read about this default in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: Thank you but as I saw after to James (after his answer) I need to update only if a specific field has updated. Thank you by the way

Comment: @red . . . This is really much better than a trigger, in my opinion.  Triggers are maintenance nightmares.

Comment: According to your suggestion I deleted the trigger and I write timestamp directly in query from node ( new Date() )

Comment: @red . . . But you don't need to do that either.  The *database* can tell you when the row is updated.  This would apply to *all* updates, not only those made by your code.

Comment: Yea but I need to know when in the user row is update feel field and this same logic for other field because I have some configuration that expire in 24h

Comment: @red . . . If you only care about one column, then that is a different matter and a trigger is appropriate.